# How i can return value from function use Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

How i can return value from function used Alamofire . i try to print outside .responseJSON the value in ArrData is not set but i try print inside it work
this code:

```
func getDept()->NSMutableArray
{

    var ArrData:NSMutableArray = []
    let url = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
        let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
        let count = json.count
        for var index = 0; index < count;index++
        {
            ArrData.addObject(json[index]["dept"].stringValue)
        }

    }
    return ArrData
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a ***handler*** like this and a callback:

```
 func getopt(callback:(array: [String]) -> void ){

        func completion(request: NSURLRequest?, response:NSHTTPURLResponse?,result:Result<AnyObject>){
                if let rdata = result.value{
                    let data = JSON(rdata)
                    print(data)
                    let myArray = [String]
                    let objects = data.array
                    for object in objects{
                      myArray.append(object)
                    }
                    callback(myArray)
                }
         }

           let url = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
           Alamofire.request(.GET,url),
                encoding: .JSON).responseJSON(completionHandler: completion)  

}
```

You pass the array to your callback So when you call getopt where you call it you can print the array. Some like this:

```
func something (){
   getopt(callback)
}

func callback(array:[String]){
    print array[0]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it i good idea to check at least README.md of the framework which you are going to use in your code

> Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously. Asynchronous
>   programming may be a source of frustration to programmers unfamiliar
>   with the concept, but there are very good reasons for doing it this
>   way.
>
> Rather than blocking execution to wait for a response from the server,
>   a callback is specified to handle the response once it's received. The
>   result of a request is only available inside the scope of a response
>   handler. Any execution contingent on the response or data received
>   from the server must be done within a handler.